# Unable to use ffprobe in fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, npm

I was intended to use ffprobe function to extract video information and here is my code:

```
var FFmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
//...
var convert_using_ffmpeg = function (source, target) {

    var tempfile = path.join(config.tmproot, path.basename(target));

    new FFmpeg({ source: source })
        .withVideoCodec('libx264')
        .withVideoBitrate('512')
        .withAudioQuality(5)
        .withAudioCodec('libmp3lame')
        .withSize('360x288')
        //.ffprobe(function(err,data) {
        //  console.dir(data);
        //})
        .toFormat('flv')
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
        })
        .saveToFile(tempfile, function () {
            fs.rename(tempfile, target);
        });
};
```

The compiler simply said `Object #<FfmpegCommand> has no method 'ffprobe` when I execute the program. The fluent-ffmpeg API says I should add FFMPEG_PATH and FFPROBE_PATH environment variable before executing, but the fact is I could execute ffmpeg directly in command line even if it does not exist in PATH environment variable, and the node.js program runs successfully without evoking the ffprobe function. Plus the API also says ffprobe comes together with most distribution of ffmpeg, if so, how can I add ffprobe to the environment variable separately?

I'm using fluent-ffmpeg 1.7.0 currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the documentation you've read is actually for 2.x rather than 1.x.

Try upgrading your fluent-ffmpeg module with `npm install --save fluent-ffmpeg@2.0.0-rc1`

Comment: I tried but it seems that the module does not work at all after that, I can only get the output `An error occurred: spawn ENOENT`

Comment: Have you definetly got ffprobe in your PATH? It's not always bundled with ffmpeg.

Comment: nope, i can't find ffprobe because i only have one ffmpeg.exe, but the problem seems unrelated to ffprobe since I have commented them.

Comment: You will also need ffprobe.exe then as fluent-ffmpeg uses it to gather metadata before processing.

Comment: If this doesn't work, I'd suggest opening an issue on that actual project rather than emailing maintainers as there's a pre-huge amount of knowledge from other people using and watching the project at https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues

Answer (score 5):

For ffprobe, similar should be done for other extensions

This way no need of ffmpeg having to be installed in os

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var ffprobe = require('ffprobe-static');
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobe.path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the FFprobe path before calling it:

```
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath("c:\\program files\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe");
ffmpeg.ffprobe(sourceFile.path, function(err, metadata) {
    if (err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(metadata);
    }
});
```

Comment: thx for help but i almost forget how i solved this problem ._.

Comment: I still haven't learned exactly what PATH is (I was trying to configure it w7 for an hour but didn't have any luck) and this fixed it perfectly.

Comment: does this answer can be aplied to a server side in node js environment? And if so how ca I can do it

Answer (score 0):

I was working on Electron project, my Node version is 10.x.x, I ran into this problem and tried multiple things, finally following solved my issue:

1. After ffmpeg v4.0.0 you need to download binaries if you don't have already
   [FF Binaries](https://ffbinaries.com/downloads)
2. you need to set binaries path explicitly into your node project.

```
    const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
    var ffmpegPath = require("ffmpeg-binaries");
    ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
    ffmpeg.setFfprobePath("D:\\sandbox\\node-proj\\binaries\\ffprobe.exe");
```